# Can i install net framework 4 application on embeded windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7, embedded, portability

Can I install and run an application developed using .NET Framework 4 on a device which has Embeded Windows 7 operating system?
I am going to buy such a device which has embeded Windows 7, so need to know if I need something special for my application to run on that device.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it is Windows 7 SP1.

Check it out :

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/downloads/windows-embedded-compatible-applications-chooser.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can run an application developed in .NET 4.0, It's supported in Windows Embedded 7 SP 1 and above.

Check the link below for compatibility

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows-embedded/2015/08/10/microsoft-net-framework-versions-supported-by-windows-embedded-products/